# html5 canvas background img

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

when i write a img to the back ground of a canvas it works but if i refresh it disapears please help this is a really annoying bug in my page. heres a sample bit of code that is doing it

```
<img id="back" src="back.jpg" alt="background" width="200" height="300">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("back");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);


ctx.moveTo(20,375);
ctx.lineTo(150,375);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(70,375);
ctx.lineTo(70,50);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(70,120);
ctx.lineTo(130,50);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(70,50);
ctx.lineTo(180,50);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(180,50);
ctx.lineTo(180,100);
ctx.stroke();


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time your script executes, the image might not yet be loaded. Run your drawing code from the `onload` event of the image to make sure it happens only after it's been loaded.